# Copy a Table from one DB to another

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with about 250 records that I need to copy from a test to a production database.
The table includes an "qid" identity column that must be preserved with the copy (I can't re-number the rows, or re-start numbering).

For example if I add records 251, 252 and 253 in the test database, then copy it to the production database, I want the next record in production to be 254 (NOT 251).

Any ideas how to automate this?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[question](
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_question_id]  DEFAULT (newid()),
    [name] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [created] [datetime] NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_question_created]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
    [qid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_question] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: use SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Tool ON; and insert data from source to target. Assumiing use can access source database from target database. After you are done with import set the identity insert to Off

Comment: If any answers were helpful please acknowledge by accepting as answer. That will encourage users to answer more questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this(assumiing use can access source database from target database)

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TargetDB.[dbo].[question] ON;

Insert into TargetDB.[dbo].[question](column1, column2, column3)
select column1, column2, column3 from SourceDB.[dbo].[question]

SET IDENTITY_INSERT TargetDB.[dbo].[question] Off;
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like just the thing.  I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select * into targetdb.dbo.question from source.dbo.question
```

Comment: If the target table is not created, this query will create the defination and import the data.